# What does it mean in a job description: " Able to build confidence in others, and remove"?

Tags: performance-reviews, job-description

I saw the following line in a job description:

> Self directed, follows through on commitments. Able to build confidence in others, and remove.

I understand the last word as a contraction to mean "remove confidence in others".

I take this to mean manage the performance of individuals in a team, and build confidence with your boss, through a pattern of delivery.

But the phrase "... and remove [confidence in others]" seems a strange way of saying manage the performance of individuals in a team. It almost seems to be saying "know when to send signals that somebody is not delivering in a way appropriate to the workplace."

My question is: **What does it mean in a job description: " Able to build confidence in others, and remove"?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about (a) speculating about what someone writing a job description might've meant, (b) something (presumably) appearing in only a single job description (or the job descriptions of a single company or recruiter) as opposed to something appearing in many job descriptions and (c) probably relating to a writing mistake. This makes any answers we can give largely opinion-based and this question very unlikely to be applicable to others.

Comment: it could also mean "...and remove [others]". Maybe you're applying to be a hit-man.

Comment: Why don't you just [call them and ask](https://www.digitalasset.com/careers/1227503/technical-product-manager)?

Comment: Remove confidence in others if they get too cocky, so they feel some pressure to perform of course ;) We would not want them to spin out of our control which could easily happen if they realize how good they really are.

Comment: The problem if they realize you have people dedicated to regulate that, then they start counting their real worth to the company as the sum of their wages and those peoples wages, which is of course in one sense true.

Comment: If it's for a job with Junk Luggers it makes perfect sense (almost).

Comment: It's just a typographical error, it's a non-issue.

Comment: It could be 'remove obstacles' as I see someone else mentioned.

Comment: There’s a period after “remove”.  They must have something against punctuation, and are hiring for a lead editor who will inspire the rest of the editors and assist the company in its campaign to remove periods (or possibly punctuation in general).

Comment: I found the ad via Google. The very next line reads "Excellent written and verbal communication" skills. I thought that was cutely ironic. :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It seems to me that it is almost certainly a mistake in the job description.

It seems like they are missing a few words that should go after "remove". They probably meant to write "removes obstacles that can come in the way of collaboration" or something along those lines.

I highly doubt they want you to remove people's confidence!

Comment: You seem very confident in this answer. You might want to dial it back a bit. :-p

Comment: Some people need their confidence removed, though.

Answer (score 32):

It means that the person creating the job description did a bad job of cut and pasting.

Comment: … and also that nobody proofread the document before issuing it!

Comment: She did a good job at cutting though...

Comment: LOL a great answer.

Comment: Maybe she lost the original copy after she cut and pasted.

Answer (score 0):

It is literally as stated the ability to remove confidence in others if they get too cocky, so they feel some pressure to perform of course ;) We would not want them to spin out of our control which could easily happen if they realize how good they really are.

---

The problem if they realize you have people dedicated to regulate that, then they start counting their real worth to the company as the sum of their wages and those peoples wages, which is of course in one sense true.